# Google Calendar API - Create Events to Send Updates

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a few 'flags' to my Google Calendar Event.  I am using the PHP API.  Most specifically I am trying to set the ['sendUpdates'=>'all'] flag, so that whenever the event is modified, all those on the attendees list will get notified.  I have tried to add this parameter upon inserting/creating the event.  I have also tried using patch.  But it does not seem to be working.

Here is some sample code:

```php
$opts = [ 
  'start' => [
    'date' => '2021-10-11',
    'timeZone' => 'US/Pacific'
  ],  
  'end' => [
    'date' => '2021-10-11',
    'timeZone' => 'US/Pacific'
  ],  
  'summary' => 'TEST EVENT',
  'description' => 'Test description',
  'attendees' => [['email'=>'test@test.com']],  
  'guestsCanModify' => false,
  'guestsCanInviteOthers' => true,
  'guestsCanSeeOtherGuests' => true,
  'reminders' => [
    'useDefault' => true,
  ],  
  'sendUpdates' => 'all',
];
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event($opts);
$new_event = $service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);
```

Then after this didn't work, I just tried to 'patch' the event with the following:

```php
$service->events->patch($calendar_id, $new_event['id'], $new_event, ['sendUpdates'=>'all']);
```

None of this is working to properly set the 'sendUpdates' flag.  It DOES create the event.  Pretty much ran out of options on how to fix this.  Documentation is pretty unclear about how to do this, and can't find much on Stack Overflow or anywhere else.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to setting the [`sendUpdates`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#parameters) parameter to `all`. Beforehand you have to keep in mind that `sendUpdates` is a parameter, not a property. Therefore you should set it in the [method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource.html#_insert), not in the request body.  So you only have to modify the script to look like this:

```php
$opts = [ 
  'start' => [
    'date' => '2021-10-11',
    'timeZone' => 'US/Pacific'
  ],  
  'end' => [
    'date' => '2021-10-11',
    'timeZone' => 'US/Pacific'
  ],  
  'summary' => 'TEST EVENT',
  'description' => 'Test description',
  'attendees' => [['email'=>'test@test.com']],  
  'guestsCanModify' => false,
  'guestsCanInviteOthers' => true,
  'guestsCanSeeOtherGuests' => true,
  'reminders' => [
    'useDefault' => true,
  ],  
];
$optionalParameters = array(
    "sendUpdates" => "all"
);
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event($opts);
$new_event = $service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event, $optionalParameters);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this.  This did work.  However a couple other questions.  I tried to update some of the other fields this way, and did not work.  Such as the 'guestsCanInviteOthers', etc.  

I get this error:  (update) unknown parameter: 'guestsCanModify'

Comment: The other question I have is that I have set the calendar, where this event lives in, to the setting that upon event modification all attendees should get an email.  So it appears to me I shouldn't even have to have to apply the flag 'sendUpdates => true'.  But this calendar setting is not having any affect when I make updates to events via the API.  When I modify events through the website, I get email updates.  Why is this setting not working via the API?

Comment: I am glad that your question got solved. If my answer was useful you can give it a green check to signal its usefulness to the rest of the community. To follow the community guidelines I strongly advise you to ask the extra questions in a new separate question.